# Custom segue in Storyboard Unwind Segue causing 'Application tried to present modally an active controller" Error swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, uistoryboard

Hey guys I need a solution to this, My custom segue when unwinding is causing a crash AFTER the segue completes how do I fix??

My custom Segue (Works fine when called using perform segue ):

```
import UIKit
class SegueFromLeft: UIStoryboardSegue {
override func perform() {
    let src = self.source
    let dst = self.destination

    src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   options: .curveEaseInOut,
                   animations: {
                    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    },
                   completion: { finished in
                    src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    )
}
```

}

[Screen shot of storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKky3.png)

Error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <Free.PhotoViewController: 0x7fa4ff97eaa0>.'
```

---

Comment: If you want to use a custom unwind segue then you must create a specific custom unwind segue class; ie. one that doesn't call `present` since the destination in an unwind is already in the view stack.  See https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/03/ios-unwind-segue-custom-animation/

Comment: what could I replace present with ? @paulw11 thanks for the help !!

Comment: You need to do whatever you need to do to remove the current view controller and any intervening view controllers until you get back to the destination view controller; so if you have a single modally presented view controller then you would `dismiss` it.  If you had multiple view controllers on a navigation controller then you would `popToViewController`